# Rxjs observable mergeAll late subscriber not receiving any emits

Tags: rxjs

Consider the following code:

```
var notifySubj = new Subject<Observable<number>>();
var notify$ = notifySubj.pipe(mergeAll());
const saveSubj = new Subject<number>();
const saveAction$ = saveSubj.pipe(
  mergeMap((n) => fromFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + n)),
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
);
const temp$: Observable<number> = saveAction$.pipe(map((r) => 1));
// notify$.subscribe((e) => console.log(e));  when placed here it emits
notifySubj.next(temp$);

saveAction$.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
notify$.subscribe((e) => console.log(e)); // no notifications
// even when emission after subscribe
saveSubj.next(3);
saveSubj.next(4);
saveSubj.next(5);
```

Even though I call saveSubj after I subscribe notify$ I don't get any values.
Is there another way to make this work?
P.S.1 : it is crucial that I can subscribe to notify$ late
P.S.2 : I don not want any values that were emitted prior to subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The solution

In your case, you simply need to use a [`ReplaySubject`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject) for `notifySubj`.

That is, you could just replace:

```js
var notifySubj = new Subject<Observable<number>>();
```

by:

```js
var notifySubj = new ReplaySubject<Observable<number>>();
```

Here's a playground example that illustrates the fix: https://playcode.io/1346187

---

I added two extra emissions to `saveSubj` to make sure your last requirement ("I don't want any values that were emitted prior to subscribe") is still satisfied:

```js
saveSubj.next(1);            // I added this line...
notifySubj.next(temp$);
saveSubj.next(2);            // ... and this one.
saveAction$.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
notify$.subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
saveSubj.next(3);            // only these...
saveSubj.next(4);            // ... three events...
saveSubj.next(5);            // ... are processed.
```

---

### How it works

By making `notifySubj` a `ReplaySubject`, anything that consumes it (in this case, `notify$`) will receive all its past emissions when they do get subscribed to.
This allows your `notify$` to receive the `temp$` that was emitted to `notifySubj` prior to your listener subscribing to anything.

Now, the trick is to **not** actually replay the "end product", the result of `notifySubj.pipe(mergeAll())`, because this **would** also result in the "obsolete" events being processed!

This is achieved by making only `notifySubj` replay its values:

```js
var notifySubj = new ReplaySubject<Observable<number>>();
var notify$ = notifySubj.pipe(mergeAll());
```

The only thing that gets replayed here is: "watch for `temp$`", rather than the emissions resulting from the `mergeAll()`.

---

Alternatively, had we chosen to replay the output of `notify$`:

```js
var notifySubj = new Subject<Observable<number>>();
var notify$ = notifySubj.pipe(mergeAll(), shareReplay());
```

... then all of the values passed to `saveSubj`, even prior to your listeners being set up, would have been processed.